# Getting "Error: Unable to release unknown resource.\n at SessionPool.release"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdbms, google-cloud-spanner

I am using GCP spanner as my project RDBMS . Lately I am getting a lot of error like the one mentioned above in the logs. Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong here ?

I tried going through google docs, but found very little on the above error . Is it something related to session pool configuration ? How this can be resolved ?

Note: I have only 1 spanner db, which is running on 1 instance on GCP.

Any help is deeply appreciated :)

Thanks

ps:

```
Error: Got unhandled rejection {"stack":"Error: Unable to release unknown resource.\n    at SessionPool.release (/testProject/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/build/src/session-pool.js:241:19)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)","message":"Unable to release unknown resource.","resource":{}}
at process.on (/testProject/index.js:22:17)
```

Comment: Could you please provide what client library and version you are using. Additionally could you provide a code snippet to reproduce this issue.

Comment: If you could provide more information, that would help. We're doing further investigations on the issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/716#issuecomment-548043518).

Comment: @skuruppu I have replied in the issue the required info . This is being tracked in
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-spanner/issues/716 . So I suppose the further communication will take place there.

Thanks for the help :)